# Android: Zoom in and Zoom out in page curl

Tags: java, android, curl

I am using http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/2013/07/page-curl-effect-in-android.html this link for curling page. Now i want to zoom a page when user touches the pages or by pressing zoom button in page curl but i can not figure it out that how to zoom pages. I don't know whether it's possible or not. I have tried so many other solution for zooming but not getting proper way to do it. If any one have idea how to do it then please guide me for the same.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Zoom a view group](https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/source/browse/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java?r=9ee0fc72b4783e23cdfeda6d46c6a948af855d78)

> Please go through this link, the zoom view class is a class can be used as view group , you can set this class as parent for the view that u want to zoom. i have used this source to zoom my view group.